# Raphael JS and screenshot on div

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael, screenshot

I have a div with a background image, and 2 images (c1 et c2) on this background. c1 and c2 use Raphael JS class.
I would like to download a png image (or jpg) with my background image and c1 and c2.

I tried to use Canvas2Image on my main div, but i don't see c1 and c2 when i download image.

Do you have an idea ? A class to make a div screenshot with all components on this div ?

Thanks you all,

Answer (score 0):

**Why the "images" are missing**

RaphaelJS draws with SVG so your c1,c2 drawings are not actually images -- they are SVG.

The problem is that SVG drawn onto html5 canvas triggers a security restriction that in turn stops exporting the canvas into an image (`context.toDataURL` is turned off by when the canvas is tainted).

This means Canvas2Image cannot display your c1,c2 image-svgs.

**A workaround**

First, draw your background on your main canvas.

```
context.drawImage(bkImage,0,0);
```

Second, convert your RaphaelJS drawings into a **real images** (not SVG) and draw them on the main canvas.

1. Export one of your your RaphaelJS drawings (either c1 or c2) as SVG. One library that exports to SVG is [Raphael.Export](https://github.com/AliasIO/Raphael.Export)
2. Convert that SVG (from#1) to html5 Canvas drawing commands. [See #3 for one way to convert svg to canvas commands].
3. Draw the commands (from#2) onto a separate html5 canvas. One library that both converts SVG to Canvas commands (==#2) and also draws them to Canvas (==#3) is [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg).
4. Create an imageObject from the separate canvas (from#3). You can use the Html5 Canvas native command `canvas.toDataURL()` to create a data url that can be used as an image.src for a new imageObject.

   ```
   var c1 = new Image;
   c1.src = secondCanvas.toDataURL();
   ```
5. Draw that **real image** onto your main canvas.

   ```
   context.drawImage(c1,0,0);
   ```

Repeat #1-5 with c2.

Finally, now that you have security compliant images (not SVG), you can directly export your canvas content to an image (again, with `context.toDataURL`). You won't even need Canvas2Image if your div only contains the background image plus c1,c2.

**A possible simpler alternative**

SVG and Canvas drawing commands are extremely similar. If c1,c2 don't rely on non-drawing RaphaelJS methods you could fairly easily draw c1,c2 using native Canvas drawing commands (bypassing Raphael entirely).

**A future alternative**

Both SVG and Canvas have remarkably similar drawing abilities.

But SVG adds full DOM capabilities -- full html element events & properties. And Canvas focuses on rendering speed -- rendering hundreds of shapes at 60 frames per second.

The organization that recommends how browsers work (W3C) receives RFP's about [making SVG & Canvas drawings compatible](http://svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/)

However, SVG-Canvas interactivity is not currently available.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try to use it :)

Comment: I can't use this method :( because i can't use juste c1 and c2 src. c1 and c2 can rotate or zoom in/out. I try lot of functions and method, but i can't make the same base image with c1, c2 on a simple png

Do you know a technology to make screenshot with div and all contents ? I know wkhtmltopdf but it's for entire page...

thanks you

Comment: If you also need to scale or rotate you can use [html5 canvas transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations) (`context.scale` and `context.rotate`) to zoom and rotate your SVG while they are turned into .PNGs. No, there is no built-in ability to screen grab a div. This inability is for security reasons -- you wouldn't want a hacker to capture an image of your bank data.